# Jackson ObjectMapper with arbitrary JSON keys

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, android-assets

I'm using Jackson 1.9.5 in an Android project to parse JSON files.

So far I haven't had any problems, and can parse files fine using the following code:

```
AssetManager mgr = getAssets();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

try {
    InputStream ifp = mgr.open("detail_schema.json");
    schema = mapper.readValue(ifp, DetailSchema.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Where the DetailSchema class consists of a mix of primitive types and classes. I'm now running into a problem where I want to parse some JSON like the following:

```
"fields": {
    "Suburb": "Paddington",
    "State": "NSW",
    "Post Code": "2074",
    "Lollipop": "Foo Bar Haz"
}
```

Where I can't possibly know the map keys before hand (they can be user-defined). As such, I'm not sure what the associated Java class should look like.

Ie, for this example, it could look like:

```
public class MyClass {

    public String Suburb;
    public String State;
    public String PostCode;
    public String Lollipop;

}
```

But this may not be correct for another instance of the JSON file. Ideally I need some way for Jackson to map values to something like a [NameValuePair](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/omg/DynamicAny/NameValuePair.html). I suspect that the automatic object mapping may not be an option in this case - can someone confirm or deny this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have two options. Either you can use [readTree in ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree(java.io.InputStream)), which returns a [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html). Working with a `JsonNode` is much like working with a tree, so you can get children nodes, read values, et cetera:

```
InputStream ifp = mgr.open("detail_schema.json");
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(ifp);
JsonNode fields = root.get("fields");
for (JsonNode children : fields) {
    // ...
}
```

Then you'd need to build your `DetailSchema` object manually.

Or, you can let Jackson deserialize it as a `Map`, in which case you'd use your code but where `MyClass` would be like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public Map<String, Object> fields;

    // getter/setters
}
```

You can probably type the map values as `String` as well if you are sure the inputs are text in json. (Actually, I'm not sure what type enforcement Jackson does, maybe it will allow anything anyway...)

Comment: You actually don't have to use a custom class in order to get a `Map`, you can have Jackson deserialize directly to an implementation of the `Map` interface, e.g.: `Map jsonFields = mapper.readValue(ifp, HashMap.class)`

Comment: @brianmearns you should make that into a new answer!